# Count the number of ways numbers 1,2,…,n can be divided into two sets of equal sum

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, recursion

> count the number of ways numbers 1,2,…,n can be divided into two sets of equal sum.

This is my recursive algorithm, what is wrong here?:

```cpp
int f(int sum,int i){//sum is the current sum, i is the current indx (<=n)
    if(i>n){
        return ((2*sum)==(n*(n+1)/2));//ie sum==totalsum/2
    }
    int cnt=f(sum,i+1)+f(sum+i,i+1);//move to i+1 or add i to sum and then move to i+1
    return cnt;
}
```

```cpp
For example, if n=7, there are four solutions:
{1,3,4,6} and {2,5,7}
{1,2,5,6} and {3,4,7}
{1,2,4,7} and {3,5,6}
{1,6,7} and {2,3,4,5}
ie f(0,1)=7
```

Answer is **f(0,1)** for any n (n is globally defined)

Thanks!

Comment: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the number of *ordered* pairs of sets $(A,B)$ such that the elements of $A$ (and of $B$) sum to $n(n+1)/4$.
Simply divide the result by $2$ to account for symmetries.

Besides, your algorithm has complexity $\Omega(2^n)$ so I doubt you'll meet the time constraint in the link you provided.

You can get an $O(n^3)$-time dynamic-programming algorithm as follows:

> Let $OPT[n, x]$ be the number of ways the numbers in $\{1, \dots, n\}$ can be partitioned into an ordered pair of sets $(A,B)$ such that the elements of $A$ sum to $x$ and those of $B$ sum to $n(n+1)/2 -  x$. 
>  
>  
>
>  Then, $OPT[0, 0] = 1$, $OPT[n][x] = 0$ if $n<0$ or $x<0$, and 
>
>  $$OPT[n,x] = OPT[n-1, x-n] + OPT[n-1, x]$$
>
>  Now, assuming that $n(n+1)/2$ is even, the solution you are looking for is: $\frac{1}{2}OPT[n][ n(n+1)/4 ]$.